# Hydrogen ozonide existence

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, covalent-compounds

Does the hydrogen ozonide exist? I mean if this compound could be found in Nature

$$HO_3$$

I am interested in the theoretical or phenomenological of such a chemical compound...

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  It exists in the atmosphere, is proposed to be intermediate in various atmospheric reactions and has been experimentally detected.

See

[*Science* Vol**285** No.5424(1999): p81](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/285/5424/81.abstract)

Note:  Full text is available after free registration.

Comment: Could you provide me some alternative paper (free online available) to study the subject? Chemistry is cool! And ozonides are pretty interesting and generally not very well known compounds by the general public (like xenon chemistry or non-stoichometric compounds).

Comment: http://www.chem.ucla.edu/~ana/pdf/3.pdf